# AS3 real-time multiplayer score

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash

I'm developing a game for Android and iOS using AS3. My problem is that my game is 99% completed but I'm trying to do a Online Multiplayer Score.

For example: Player1 - 100 points versus Player2 - 500 points.

Untill here everything is going gratly. I'm saving scores to database and loading back to display. My problem is that because I need to set data to database and load it back when PVP is in the last second (1 sec remain) I can send data to database, but sometimes, when load it back, I get errors and no database is loaded.

Is there a simple way to share and display data without using database in AS3. I think if I don't use database, things gonna be faster, but I don't know how to do this!

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to use when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: If you don't see, i did my question and i show the way i'm doing. I try many other ways to do this but nothing is working. So i decided to ask help... All answers i found here is how to build an online game using data servers. This way i have already passed. Now i want a faster way and with less errors to show score in real time

Comment: Fast would be PvP and sockets.

Comment: Rather then loading back to score store the updated score in your local model and after getting success message from the database use the same score to display which you have stored it in you model. Try this hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: In my opinion the score should be tracked by the clients themselves locally.  Hook the score into whatever event is used to increase/decrease the score for X player.  And show the score but once in a while do a call to the DB to see if the score fits what is being locally represented and adjust accordingly.  It you fail to fetch the score from the DB just use the local count instead.

Comment: Thanks guys but this way you all are saying will not show to scores to one another in real-time... I already solve this problem using php + database... i set in the end of pvp room a timer to catch last updates from database... this is saving my problem